# Hover selection is too fast

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way to slow down the select when hovering with the mouse? My system currently selects almost instantly instead of waiting long enough for me to decide whether I want to select a given item or window.

Answer (score 1):

In XP, this was easy with [TweakUI](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-xp). In Windows 7, you can change it by [manually editing](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1884-mouse-hover-time-change.html) [the registry](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread13191.html).

1. Open the registry editor (`regedit.exe`)
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse`
3. Edit the `MouseHoverTime` entry to set the time Windows waits before activating a hovered item (the number is in milliseconds, so if you want Windows to wait two seconds, use 2,000—make sure to set the *base* to *Decimal*)
4. Log out and back in (or just reboot) for it to take effect

Comment: merely linking to answers is not considered an answer here at SuperUser, please copy the registry edit information to your answer.

Comment: That’s just a stop-gap. I’m looking for an app to do it because editing the registry is not a good solution.

Comment: Ah, a placeholder, sneaky ;->

Comment: Well I don’t know about the OP’s urgency, so it does the job, but it’s not pretty. (I am surprised that the [`Ultimate Windows Tweaker`](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista)—aka Windows 7 TweakUI—does not have this function.) `:-|`

Comment: So much for "Ultimate".